# Windows Forms app migrated to UWP doesn't appear when installed from AppxBundle

Tags: uwp

I've migrated a Windows Forms app [KeePass 2.x](https://github.com/panteam-net/KeePass2.x) to the UWP platform using Windows Application Packaging Project. The app starts well with VS 2019 debugger under Debug or Release config.
I created an [AppxBundle](https://github.com/panteam-net/KeePass2.x/actions/runs/322640002). It installs the app but the app's window never appears.
I tried to debug the installed package with VS 2019 but it shows no exception only that Thread xxxx exited with 0 code. There is nothing suspicious in the Event Log either.

I would appreciate any ideas on what I've done wrong or what can I do more to find the issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello, when migrating Win32 desktop applications through Desktop-Bridge, some preparations are required to avoid using some unsupported APIs. You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-prepare) for testing

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The application compatibility tool found some unsupported API used. It showed some warnings (not errors). Does it mean that we have no options to debug our apps in such a case?

Comment: Hello, you can adjust the application code according to the tool's prompts. If you want to debug the desktop-bridge application, you can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-debug)